# Understanding the FilterLoggingBuilderExtensions.AddFilter overloads

Tags: c#, .net, logging

Most of the `FilterLoggingBuilderExtensionsAddFilter()` method overloads accept a `Func<>` delegate that provides the actual "filter". I can't find any information about the meaning of the "string" parameters.

Looking at the [LoggerFilterRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerfilterrule?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) where the delegate finally gets passed to did not help either. Its also not documented in the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e6f3aa95aeaa5a36c4be71d1964ddc2eeaddfd09/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/src/LoggerFilterRule.cs). Am I missing something?

For example, what would I use

`AddFilter(ILoggingBuilder, Func<String,String,LogLevel,Boolean>)`

for?

I was searching for a way to filter log messages by message content.